# How to run a function with different parameters parallely in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a function called computeStrokes and I need to call it twice with different parameters.. There is a method in Asynctask called **executeOnExecutor** which allows a asynctask to run two threads parallely.I was not able to understand how to call this function twice within the **doInBackground** method of the AsyncTask.
Can Someone just help me with the code of this section i.e **doInBackground**

Comment: Why not to make one call  after another in doInBackground or start two AsyncTasks probably one after another?

Comment: Two Asynctasks one after another will run serially .Api changes since HoneyComb

Answer (score 0):

If you really need run 2 tasks in parallel from an AsyncTask then you can probably start 2 tasks in doInBackground and wait in there for the completion of both. This can be achieved with the help of [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) and a [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)